# Building a website, html and css files won't link. Any ideas why?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website for a school project, and in one directory with all the files (index.html, style.css) the website will load just fine, (as a local file) but after I deployed the files, none of the css loaded, and neither did the pictures. I linked the css file with the html file with this line of code: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="Termux/css/style.css">` And i made sure all the tags were right in the css file. (I dont have enough space to put it in here) Any ideas why?

EDIT: The directory for the style.css file is Termux/css/style.css and the directory for index.html is Termux/public/index.html NOTES: I am using firebase hosting, and for this project I am using a Chromebook.

EDIT TWO: a minimal reproductible example of the html;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <!-- update the version number as needed -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/7.14.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/7.14.4/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/7.14.4/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/7.14.4/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/7.14.4/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <!-- initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Termux/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="logo">
                  <img src="bonklylogo.png" alt="Image" height="64" width="64">
              </div>
              <div class="nav-links">
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Trade</a></li>
                       <li><a href="https://bonklyinvestments.web.app/signup.html">Sign Up</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

an example of the css;

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.main{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relatve;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #0B3B39,#045FB4, #045FB4, #0B2F3A, #0B243B);
}
nav{
    width: 80%;
    position: sticky;
    margin: 20px auto;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.logo{
    flex-basis: 20%;
}
.logo img{
    width: 64px;
}
.nav-links{
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
}
.nav-links ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.nav-links ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;

}
```

NOTE: some of this is actual code from my project so there may be excess code in some places.

UPDATE: I looked at the Sources tab in the website, and in the css fie it shows no code. Almost like the code didn't upload correctly. Which dosen't make sense (to me anyway) because it worked when I ran it locally, and I've got a previous version to work correctly. Still confused.

Comment: Without knowing the deployed directory structure and the paths you used in the HTML we cannot know why it is not linking correctly. You gave the path you are using the HTML, so can you confirm what the deployed directory structure is?

Comment: We need to see a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I believe `Termux` is the root of your project or using apache and the structure like `public_html/Termux` where index file located if so please refer to css as follows:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">`

I think your project root file is changing when u deploy that what causing the issue ... use browser console get more info about the error.